# How to make sure a javascript script is added last in Joomla

Tags: javascript, joomla

Throughout my site, I have multiple modules that use `JFactory::getDocument()->addScript` to add various bits and pieces of javascript to be run. I have a problem though, I can't tell what order javascripts are being added into `JFactory::getDocument()->_script['text/javascript']`, and I need to make sure one piece of javascript is added **last** regardless of the order previous pieces of javascript are added.

Is there any sure fire way to be absolutely sure it's added last, **without** adding the other javascript bits to the start of the `JFactory::getDocument()->_script['text/javascript']` variable?

Comment: Your template should be the very last to load, after the components, plugins, modules, etc... So add your call to the very bottom of your template index.php and it should load very last.

Comment: No go, the javascript is added before both the component javascript and the module javascript.

Answer (score 0):

use addCustomTag instead

```
$document->addCustomTag('<script src="SOURCE" type="text/javascript"></script>');
```